# How to bind current months data to calendar bootstrap, cause only previous months are binding

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

```
$('#task-calendar-new').calendar({ 
        months: theMonths,
        days: theDays,
        popover_options: {
            placement: 'top',
            html: true,
            trigger: 'manual'
        },
        req_ajax: {
            type: 'GET',
            url: "@Url.Action("getFullTaskCalendar", "Task")/" + $('#task-calendar-new').find('div.visualmonthyear').text()
        }
    });
```

this gets a json request from the controller, but when navigating to previous months its binds correctly. But not for future or current months

this is the library im using bootstrap_calendar by bic.cat (http://bic.cat) & xero (http://xero.nu)
    https://github.com/xero/bootstrap_calendar

[this is a snippet of the data that i return to the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chV45.png)

Comment: What is `.calendar`? is that a library? I also don't see any "bind" actions happening in your code.

Comment: Are you sure the GET request is bringing back the data you expect to see?

Comment: @AnonymousSB added the library to the question and yes the calendar is recieving correct data

Comment: @Crowcoder there is a picture of my data that i return to .calendar via ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that the .calendar events doesnt see single dates as a valid date so for example 01/12/2018 it must 1/12/2018. Otherwise the .calendar wont read it as calendar event